# Meteor template not updating when template helper re-runs

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I am trying to make a custom form wizard that will contain different autoform steps based on certain conditions. A simplified meteorPad example is linked below. When the reactive data source(session variable) changes the reactive computation(template helper) runs, confirmed by console output. The template, however, is not updated and still has the same number of steps. Is there something I need to do to make the template update correctly? Thanks!
http://meteorpad.com/pad/cPWShRiTKYpBaMahn/Leaderboard

**html**

```
<body>
  {{> basicWizard}}
  {{> changeSteps}}
</body>

<template name="basicWizard">
<!--shouldn't the steps variable update when the helper runs?-->
  {{> wizard id="basic-wizard" steps=steps}}
</template>

<template name="changeSteps">
 <button id="changeStepsButton"> change number of Steps </button>
</template>
```

**client code**

```
Session.set('twoSteps', false);

information = new SimpleSchema({
  password: {
    type: String,
    label: 'password',
  },
});
confirm = new SimpleSchema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    label: 'blah',
  },
});

Template.basicWizard.helpers({
    steps: function() {
      var ret = [];
      if (Session.get("twoSteps")) {
      ret[ret.length] = 
        {
          id: 'information',
          title: 'Information',
          schema: information,
        }
      }
      ret[ret.length] = 
        {
          id: 'confirm',
          title: 'Confirm',
          schema: confirm  ,
        }
      console.log("num steps: " + ret.length)
      return ret;
    }
  });

Template.changeSteps.events({
  "click #changeStepsButton": function (event) {
    Session.set('twoSteps', !Session.get("twoSteps")); 
  }, 
})
```

Comment: Personally for me, the meteorpad does not load, it stays in the loading state forever, and in console I see 400 and 404 error codes. Maybe this is a problem of my local setup (firewall, etc.), but can you post your code somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the hassle is that the Wizard doesn't handle steps reactively.  I suspect it's the following code in the Wizard package:

The "new WizardConstructor" call below is where I think the reactivity is breaking:
    Template.wizard.created = function() {
      var id = this.data.id || defaultId;
      this.wizard = wizardsById[id] = new WizardConstructor(this.data);
    };

Somewhere in wizard constructor it does this call:
    _.each(this.steps, function(step) {
      self._initStep(step);
    });

But I don't think Meteor knows to recreate the template when "this.data" changes.  Technically the Wizard is not binding to the "steps" which is why it's not working.  I suspect the creator of the wizard package did not intend for it to be used in this way.